# Disable down scrolling while detecting down scrolling

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple welcoming page on my website that displays an image along with its title and buttons to sign up.

**Working Fiddle:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ernestsoo22/au8n9L25/)

**Problem:** I want to be able to disable scrolling of the page, while detecting any down scrolling event.

This is because I want to be able to perform some animations on the down scroll event rather than the page actually scrolling.

**Attempt:**

```
        $(document).ready(function() { 

                      var CurrentScroll = 0;
                      $(window).scroll(function(event){

                          var NextScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

                          if (NextScroll > CurrentScroll){
                             //write the codes related to down-ward scrolling here
                             /// Animations Codes Here

                          }
                          else {
                             //write the codes related to upward-scrolling here

                          }

                          CurrentScroll = NextScroll;  //Updates current scroll position
                      });
                    });
```

This is the script that I tried to detect downward scrolling, but the animation is not seen due to scrolling therefore I need a workaround.

How can I achieve what I want using jquery?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. Why you use `});` 3 times? it should be two times

Comment: what animation you want when scrolldown?

Comment: I want to be able to disable the scrolling of the page while the animation occurs @NiravJoshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to simply listen for the scroll event and forget about trying to prevent the scrolling, then take over the scrolling for the user, like so:

```
var scrollTarget = 300;
$("#divThatScrolls").scroll(function() {
    $("#divThatScrolls").animate({ scrollTop: scrollTarget+"px" });
});
```

And just change `scrollTarget` depending on where you want to scroll to.

Answer (score 0):

```
body
{
  position: fixed; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

try this

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44691262/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.